# Extract variations of a string from R column

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I have list of keywords

```
keywords=c("Minister", "President","Secretary")
```

I have a column which has different text in different rows

```
column=c("he is general Secretary of Ozon group", "He is vice president of 
our college", "He is health minister", "He is education minister")
```

is there any way to extract variations present in the column based on keywords?

the output I am looking is

```
output=c("general Secretary","vice president", "education minister", "health minister")
```

Comment: is it generally the word preceeding minister/president/ that you want to capture together with the keyword?

Comment: yes...but it can be trailing as well for other keywords eg. "Secretary to Prime Minister"

Comment: Then you definitely need to provide some logic to identify what other words you want to extract

Comment: @docendodiscimus can you help me on this. I have just started with text in R and finding it difficult

Comment: Think about how to decide whether you want the preceeding or trailing word to be captured with the keyword. What rule is there to decide this?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Currently I am only looking for preceding keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to extract the keyword + any preceeding word, you could do it like this:

```
pat <- paste0("\\w+\\s(", paste(keywords, collapse = "|"), ")")
regmatches(column, gregexpr(pat, column, ignore.case = TRUE))
#[[1]]
#[1] "general Secretary"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "vice president"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "health minister"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "education minister"
```

Or using stringr

```
library(stringr)
pat <- paste0("\\w+\\s(", paste(tolower(keywords), collapse = "|"), ")")
str_extract_all(tolower(column), pat)
```